# Issue with a SQL query on a date time field in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have to make a query that selects the elements of a collection that belong to an interval between two dates, start and end. While the startdate constraint is respected, the enddate one always seems to be two hours behind. The items extracted are greater or equal to startdate and are less than or equal to enddate minus two hours.

An example of an item is the following:

```
{
  "messageUID": "xxxxxxxxx22019-05-31T16:59:16+02:00",
  "deviceId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "dateTimeDevice": "2019-05-31T14:59:16",
  "messageId": 39,
  "release": 104,
  "VIn": 23430,
  "VOut": 20592,
  "AIn": 53,
  "AOut": 40,
  "CosPhi": 43,
  "W": 54,
  "Var": 112,
  "VA": 125,
  "WhCnt": 365009,
  "VarhCnt": 756729,
  "TimeSlot": 0,
  "MeterTS": "2019-05-31 16:59:17",
  "Sampling": 60,
  "Wh": 3422,
  "Varh": 7098,
  "WSaved": 0,
  "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2019-05-31T14:59:18.3140933Z",
  "PartitionId": 1,
  "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2019-05-31T14:59:18.29Z",
  "IoTHub": {
    "MessageId": null,
    "CorrelationId": null,
    "ConnectionDeviceId": "Device",
    "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636909297614425839",
    "EnqueuedTime": "2019-05-31T14:59:18.296Z",
    "StreamId": null
  },
  "id": "EBBBrain-1060894172",
  "_rid": "dEkOAONukRECAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "_self": 
  "dbs/dEkOAA==/colls/dEkOAONukRE=/docs/dEkOAONukRECAAAAAAAAAA==/",
  "_etag": "\"2400a2a2-0000-0c00-0000-5cf1415c0000\"",
  "_attachments": "attachments/",
  "_ts": 1559314780
}
```

The where clause of the query is as follows:

```
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "where (c.EventProcessedUtcTime >= @startdate) and ";
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "(c.EventProcessedUtcTime <= @enddate) and ";
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "(c.deviceId = @deviceId)";
sqlQuerySpec.Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
  {
    new SqlParameter("@startdate",startdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFZ")),
    new SqlParameter("@enddate",enddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFZ")), 
    new SqlParameter("@deviceId", deviceId)
  };
```

In debug it seems that the parameters are passed correctly.

I **solved** the issue changing the code as follows :

```
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "where (RIGHT(c.messageUID, 25) >= @startdate) and ";
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "(RIGHT(c.messageUID, 25) <= @enddate) and ";
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "(c.deviceId = @deviceId)";
sqlQuerySpec.Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
  {
    new SqlParameter("@startdate",DateTime.SpecifyKind(startdate,DateTimeKind.Unspecified)),
    new SqlParameter("@enddate",DateTime.SpecifyKind(enddate,DateTimeKind.Unspecified)), 
    new SqlParameter("@deviceId", deviceId)
  };
```

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: It is properly a daylight saving time issue. Are you `startdate` and `enddate` into same local timezone?

Comment: Yes, they are. For example _startdate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFZ") => "2019-08-03T00:28:43Z"  enddate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFZ") =>
"2019-08-04T00:28:43Z"_

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, I tried applying the time zone without success. I only have the problem at the top end of the query. I have also tried imposing static values ​​on startdate and enddate but the problem still occurs. The range of returned items ranges from startdate to enddate-2 hours. If it were a time zone problem it would be applied to both startdate and enddate.

Comment: Have you tried using the native value/datetime object instead of a string value?

Comment: @Frank : Yes I have tried and I got the same results.

Comment: Well we are surly overlooking something. I have not worked with CosmosDB, but one think tha fuzz me is that: How does CosmosDB knows that startdate and enddata is actual DateTime, and not just a regular string?

Comment: When i work with Json, i always use `long` (Epoch) for DateTime.

Comment: @Frank : I solved the issue. Look at the post.

Comment: Ok, so it was the timezone of the DateTime. Shouldn't you set it to Utc if they are that or Local if they should be converted to utc.

Comment: @SimoneSpagna Hi,you could summarize your solution as answer for others' references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with the following code :

```
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "where (RIGHT(c.messageUID, 25) >= @startdate) and ";
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "(RIGHT(c.messageUID, 25) <= @enddate) and ";
sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "(c.deviceId = @deviceId)";
sqlQuerySpec.Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
  {
    new SqlParameter("@startdate",DateTime.SpecifyKind(startdate,DateTimeKind.Unspecified)),
    new SqlParameter("@enddate",DateTime.SpecifyKind(enddate,DateTimeKind.Unspecified)), 
    new SqlParameter("@deviceId", deviceId)
 ;
```

Thanks to all.